# Presto SQL- convert date which is in string datatypes into date format yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, presto

**ds: date in the yyyy/mm/dd format. It is stored in the form of text and we use presto to run. no need for date function**

```
CREATE TABLE job_data(
    ds DATE,
    job_id INT NOT NULL,
    actor_id INT NOT NULL,
    event VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    language VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    time_spent INT NOT NULL,
    org CHAR(2) );

INSERT INTO job_data (ds, job_id, actor_id, event, language, time_spent, org)
VALUES ('2020-11-30', 21, 1001, 'skip', 'English', 15, 'A'),
    ('2020-11-30', 22, 1006, 'transfer', 'Arabic', 25, 'B'),
    ('2020-11-29', 23, 1003, 'decision', 'Persian', 20, 'C'),
    ('2020-11-28', 23, 1005,'transfer', 'Persian', 22, 'D'),
    ('2020-11-28', 25, 1002, 'decision', 'Hindi', 11, 'B'),
    ('2020-11-27', 11, 1007, 'decision', 'French', 104, 'D'),
    ('2020-11-26', 23, 1004, 'skip', 'Persian', 56, 'A'),
    ('2020-11-25', 20, 1003, 'transfer', 'Italian', 45, 'C');
```

here i have used **ds** as date datatype.

my code:

```
select ds, count(job_id) as jobs_per_day, sum(time_spent)/3600 as hours_spent 
from job_data  
where ds >='2020-11-01'  and ds <='2020-11-30'  
group by ds ;
```

> This is what I have done but I have to enter date in string and I
> can't understand how can I convert it into date without using any
> function. I am using mysql workbench 8.0.

Comment: You can't convert a `string ` to `date` without a function . In Presto you can use `date_parse` https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse

Comment: returning an syntax error. `select DATE_PARSE(ds, %Y %M %D), count(job_id) as jobs_per_day, sum(time_spent)/3600 as hours_spent 
from job_data  
where ds >='2020-11-01'  and ds <='2020-11-30'  
group by ds ;`

Comment: In SQL code you must use `DATE_FORMAT(ds, '%Y/%m/%d')` for to select the date as string in `yyyy/mm/dd` form. And `STR_TO_DATE(@parameter, '%Y/%m/%d')` if you want to provide a string in `yyyy/mm/dd` form to the query as the value for INSERT/UPDATE/WHERE...

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=15ff8c29d947ea043b51703c95311207

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a string  to date without a function . In Presto you can use `date_parse`. Try:

```
select cast(date_parse(ds,'%Y-%m-%d') as date) as the_date , 
count(job_id) as jobs_per_day, 
sum(time_spent)/3600 as hours_spent 
from job_data  
where the_date >='2020-11-01'  and the_date <='2020-11-30'  
group by the_date ;
```

Comment: MySQL won't use Presto function.

Comment: It is showing an error. **FUNCTION** operation_analytics.date_parse doesn't exist.**

Comment: @akina then sql server ?

Comment: @Chaudhari you should use Presto SQL, because you are asking for Presto or not ?

Comment: @Akina I know but the `OP` is asking about `Presto SQL`

Comment: @basha04 lol, I thought this stuff will work as it has same function as in sql server.

Comment: Even if they are `SQL` , there are difference between `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, `Postgress` etc. You should point the exact  database you are using